# PHP Silex microframework syntax explanation

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I've been playing around with Silex for the past couple of days. I'm having trouble understand how the following code snippet works.

I'm not interested in *what* it does but rather *how* it does it.

```
    use Silex\Application;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

    $app->get('/foo', function (Application $app, Request $request) {
       $subRequest = Request::create('/', ...);
       $response = $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST, false);

        return $response;
    });
```

I get confused around

```
function (Application $app, Request $request)
```

From my understanding that's an anonymous function being called as an argument to the $app->get method. How do the two arguments in this anonymous function work? specifically what's:

`Application $app, Request $request`?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think it does? Have you seen anything that looks like that before? Perhaps on class methods or other functions?

Comment: I had my suspicions but did not know if typehinting was possible in OOP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The implicit way that controller arguments get populated is probably one of the most confusing parts of silex.

When you define a controller via one of the HTTP verb methods, that controller can add type hints to its arguments. `Request` and `Application` are type hints for the two arguments `$app` and `$request`.

The `HttpKernel` is the part of Silex responsible for invoking the controller. It uses a `ControllerResolver` to figure out which arguments to pass in. The `ControllerResolver` will infer the arguments from the type hints.

- For a `Silex\Application` type hint, it will inject the application.
- For a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` type hint, it will inject the current request.

If you want to get a better understanding, I recommend reading [the HttpKernel source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php).

Comment: your answer was a bit more in depth then what I was looking for, I was merely interested in the syntax :) this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php is what I was looking for. Thanks!